# Debugging C program with two arguments passed

Tags: c, codelite

I have fixed some syntactical errors in my code and now the program compiles fine. But when I execute the program the outputFile is empty. outputFile should have contents of inputFile in reverse order. I am trying to debug code in `CodeLite` IDE.

I need to debug the code with two arguments passed (inputFile and outputFile). I don't seem to find that option in `CodeLite` IDE. How do I do that ?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE  *inputFile, *outputFile; 
    int fileSize;
    int pointer;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    /* Check for correct user's inputs. */
    if( argc !=3 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFile outputFile.\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Make sure input file exists. */
    if( (inputFile = fopen(argv[1], O_RDONLY))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input file doesn't exist.\n"); 
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Create output file, if it doesn't exist.  Empty the file, if it exists. */

    if((outputFile = fopen(argv[2], "a+"))) {
        fclose(inputFile);
        exit(-1);
     }


    /* Find the size of the input file. */
    fileSize = fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);


    /* Read input file and write to output file in reversed order.*/

    for(pointer=fileSize-1; pointer>=0; pointer--) {


    /*Write content in the buffer to the output file */

        while(!feof(inputFile))
        {
            fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, inputFile); //reads 256 bytes at a time
            fputs (buffer , outputFile );
        }

    }

    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `outputFile = fopen(argv[2], "a+")` will not empty the file.

Comment: Your for loop `(pointer=fileSize-1; pointer>=0; pointer--)` will of course _count_ in reverse, but that does not mean the input is _read_ in reverse. Happy debugging :-)

Comment: First, you seek to the end of the file, then try to read 256 bytes. Even if that did work (which it won't), you then attempt to write those 256 bytes to the new file in the same order (relative to the 256 byte offset) they have in the original file.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie corrected outputFile = fopen(argv[2], "w") . Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/ProjectSettings:

Project Settings >> General >> Command arguments

Comment: I don't see Project Settings>>General or Command arguments anywhere in the IDE. Is it hidden somewhere in the menus ?

Comment: Thanks @bolov I found it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the project folder
2. Select project settings
3. General -> Execution -> Program Arguments

Answer (score 0):

here you go!

Select and highlight the project.

Right-click on the project folder or go on to top, settings icon of the workspace pane.

Select project settings

General > Execution > Program Arguments

[image]